# on() does not do the live() job for me

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

It's been mentioned on the jQuery website `.live()` method is no longer recommended.
I was trying to use the `.on()` event but it does not perform as I expect. Using `.live` for the following scenario, I got no issue.

I have got a field for which I use a autocomplete plugin:

what it does is, every time you are about to put an entry, you put it in a field (generated by the plugin) like this that is when you put the first entry and the completion is done, for the second time you are entering the input, another new field with the same class is created:

```
<li id="select">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" size="0" class="input">
</li>
```

What I am trying to do is, generating a on paste handler so that every time I paste something is the input, it turns to a entry with its own tag (which is not related to the current issue anyway). When I use .live event it works as expected. It handle my paste not only for the first time, but also for the future pastes. But when I change it to .on instead of live, it only works for the first paste. The following is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".input").live('paste', function (event) {
        var element = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            var text = $(element).val();
            addItem(text);
        }, 10);
    });
});
```

Can anyone please explain why is this happening?

Comment: What is the syntax you were using when you were attempting to use the `on` method?

Comment: It should be `$('body').on('paste', ".input", function (event) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> you put it in a field (generated by the plugin) like this that is when
>   you put the first entry and the completion is done, for the second
>   time you are entering the input, another new field with the same class
>   is created

That sounds like a dynamic element. Using [**live()**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) would have bubbled that event to the `document` and then re-acted when a `paste` occurred on the `.input` element.

Replacing it with a simple `on()` like this: `$(".input").on('paste', function (event) {}` would not replicate that.

That would only be a simple bind and as soon as the element is dynamically replaced/re-added the bound events are gone as soon as the element was removed, even though it was re-added.

To replicate `live()` for dynamic elements you would need to use `on()` with delegation, which will allow you to bind the event to the closest static element, specifying the element/selector to which to delegate to.

Change your current `live()` from:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".input").live('paste', function (event) {
        var element = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            var text = $(element).val();
            addItem(text);
        }, 10);
    });
});
```

To using `on()` with delegation similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("paste", ".input", function (event) {
        var element = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            var text = $(element).val();
            addItem(text);
        }, 10);
    });
});
```

In the above the event is now bound to the `document` but delegated to the `.input` element on `paste`.

Instead of `document` you should bind to the closest static parent element. For example `body` or a closer static parent, similar to this:

```
$('body').on("paste", ".input", function (event) {...}
```

Which ever the closest static parent of the `.input` element is, though `document` or `body` will off course work fine.

Comment: Great thanks man , can u pls explain what was wrong with my version? how come it was working only once?

Comment: @ComeRun: I updated the answer to include an explanation. I think I used the correct terminology but I'm sure anyone reading this will correct me if I didn't. Hope this helps.

Comment: was awesome man but I believe you meant '.input' instead of 'document' in your last sentence right?

Comment: @ComeRun: If you are refering to this: `Instead of document you should bind to the closest static element.` I meant `document` alright. I was referring to replace `document` with the closest static parent element, similar to this: `$(closestStaticElement).on("paste", ".input", function (event) {}` means less bubbling. I added a clarification as well to the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
function addItem(text){
    console.log('Add', text)
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('paste', ".input", function (event) {
        var element = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            var text = $(element).val();
            addItem(text);
        }, 10);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RZb66/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the event is triggered only once, which may be related to:

- An event called using `.one` and not `.on`
- An event target being altered by its dom (being deleted, or moved) and thus, losing events.

I'd recommend going for a truly `.live` translation:

```
$(document).on('paste', ".input", function (event) {
    var element = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        var text = $(element).val();
        addItem(text);
    }, 10);
});
```

You can skip the ready event, as listening for an event in document will append that event to the second parameter (`.input`) each time a new one is added.